# Proof about GCD's

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Prove that if $a, b$ and $c$ are integers with $b \neq 0$ and $a=bx+cy$ for some integers $x$ and $y$, then $\text{gcd}(b,c) \le  \text{gcd}(a,b).$

---

I don't understand how to show (b,c) is less than (a,b)?

Answer (score 1):

First note that if $d \vert b$ and $d \vert c$, then $d \vert a$. Since $\gcd(b,c)$ is also a common divisor of $b$ and $c$, we have $\gcd(b,c) \vert a$. As noted, we also have $\gcd(b,c) \vert b$.

Now recall that if $e \vert a$ and $e \vert b$, then by definition $\gcd(a,b) \geq e$. Hence, we have
$$\gcd(b,c) \leq \gcd(a,b)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\ \begin{eqnarray}\color{}{(b,c)}&&\mid\, \color{sienna}b,\ \ \ \color{sienna}c \\ \Rightarrow\ (b,c)&&\mid \,\color{sienna}b\,x\!\!+\!\!\color{sienna}c\,y=\color{#c00}a\!\end{eqnarray}\bigg\rbrace\  $ so $\ \bigg\lbrace\begin{eqnarray}(b,c)&\mid&\ \color{#c00}a,\,b\\ \,\Rightarrow (b,c) &\color{#0a0}\le& (a,b) \end{eqnarray}\bigg\rbrace\ $ by $\ \bigg\lbrace\, \begin{eqnarray} &&c\rm ommon\ divisor \\ \color{#0a0}\le &&{\it greatest}\rm\,\  common\ divisor\end{eqnarray}$